# Why doesn't this MySQL stored procedure work as I want it to?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want a stored-procedure to create a temporary table, populate the table with data, then return the table. This is what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_r3(p_panel_id INT)
BEGIN
    -- create new temporary table
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(assembly_id INT, cost1 DECIMAL(10,2), cost2 DECIMAL(10,2));

    -- populate table
    SELECT sf_assembly_breakdown(assembly_id) AS dummy FROM panel_assembly WHERE panel=p_panel_id;

    -- return table
    SELECT * FROM temp;
END

CREATE FUNCTION sf_assembly_breakdown (p_assembly_id INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE cost1 DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE cost2 DECIMAL(10,2);

    -- calculate cost1, cost2 here
    ...


    -- insert data into temporary table
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT p_assembly_id , cost1, cost2;

    -- return dummy value
    RETURN NULL;
END
```

This doesn't work though! The result set returned by `sp_create_r3` is that generated by:

```
SELECT sf_assembly_breakdown(assembly_id) AS dummy FROM panel_assembly WHERE panel=p_panel_id;
```

I don't want to return this. I want to return `SELECT * FROM temp`;

Is this possible? If not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routine will return as many data sets as there are `SELECT` statements in it. So, the first data set returned is what you indicated, and the second data set returned is what you want.

There are APIs for C and PHP that I know of that are able to deal with multiple result sets returned from a routine, however if you're not using either of those then you may need to look for a library that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you set up the temporary table differently:

```
create temporary table temp select p_assembly_id, cost1, cost from panel_assembly where panel=p_panel_id;
```

or use `SELECT ... INTO` syntax.